# Conditional sampling in Pig

Tags: json, random, apache-pig, sampling

I am using elephant-bird to parse a nested JSON in Pig.  I'd like to store a sample where the probability of sampling depends on the value of a binary attribute "C" in the parsed JSON.

One way to do this conditional sampling is to split my relation based on the value of "C", and then apply the SAMPLE operator to both subrelations, each with a different sampling probability.

1. Is there a more direct and efficient way to accomplish this, in one
   pass?
2. If not, what is the recommended way to split and then combine
   the subrelations back together?  I am operating large files, so
   efficiency is a concern.